# Fill in specific cells in another workbook from a single source book with filtered rows

Tags: excel, vba

My ultimate goal is to read a range from one workbook and input it into specific cells in another workbook. The source Workbook has a range of autofiltered data in columns A-D. The destination workbook has 8 fields that need to be filled and they will always be the same. For instance, The source workbook will have the first field of the Array MyArray(x) go into the field B2 on the destination workbook. Then MyArray(x) will have x=2 which will populate D2 in the destination workbook from the next visible row in column B. So, it would look like this:

Source workbook

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User Name | AccountNo | Last3 | Software to Load |
| 3 | User 2 | 10161_4002 | MM1 | License E3 |
| 4 | User 3 | 10202_2179 | 118 |  |
| 6 | User 5 | 10141_9863 | AA5 | License-E3,Reflection |
| 7 | User 6 | 10167_3006 | B35 | RSI,Java |
| 9 | User 8 | 10176_3393 | W45 | Office365,Java |

And the destination workbook would look like this:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Name: |  | Account Number: |  |
| 3 | ID: |  | Software: |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | Name: |  | Account Number: |  |
| 6 | ID: |  | Software: |  |

So, after running to sub/function, I would have:

```
[D]=Destination    [S]=Source

[D]B2=[S]A3
[D]D2=[S]B3
[D]B3=[S]C3 
[D]D3=[S]D3
    
[D]B5=[S]A4 
[D]D5=[S]B4
[D]B6=[S]C4
[D]D6=[S]D4
```

And so on with 2 rows from the source getting put into the 8 fields of the destination workbook. I have some very basic code at this point but I know this is pretty convoluted. Here is what I've come up with so far which just loops through all of the visible rows and prints out the lines from the range from A2 through the last cell in D with data in it to the immediate window. I've removed it from my main project and just put it all in 2 new workbooks to simplify everything. Ultimately, I'm going to print each page when the destination gets all 8 fields updated and move on to the next page. My code so far:

```
Sub AddToPrintoutAndPrint()

Dim rng As Range, lastRow As Long
Dim myArray() As Variant, myString() As String
Dim cell As Range, x As Long, y As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1 ' Sheet1

lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("A2:D" & lastRow)

For Each cell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
  myArray(x) = cell.Value
  x = x + 1
Next cell

For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
  Debug.Print Trim$(myArray(x))
Next x

Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Might be better to loop through each column of filtered data or copy the filtered range somewhere else and work from that. In fact you only need to loop through one column and use the offsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: New block of code to support printing multiple lines**

```
Sub RunIt()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim coll As Collection
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rowCounter As Integer
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    
    Set coll = GetUserInfo(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    
    'This is used to keep a running total of how many rows
    'were populated. Since the entries are three rows apart
    'we can use the offset function in the loop to choose
    'the correct entry. This is also flexible enough
    'such that if you ever wanted three or more entries
    'per sheet, it will work.
    
    rowCounter = 0
    
    For Each itm In coll
        wsDest.Range("B2").Offset(rowCounter * 3).Value = itm(0)
        wsDest.Range("D2").Offset(rowCounter * 3).Value = itm(1)
        wsDest.Range("B3").Offset(rowCounter * 3).Value = itm(2)
        wsDest.Range("D3").Offset(rowCounter * 3).Value = itm(3)
        
        'Increment rowcouter, looping around if you surpass
        'two (or any future max number of items)
        rowCounter = (rowCounter + 1) Mod 2
        
        'If rowCounter has reset to 0, that means its time to
        'print or whatever yuo need to do. Do it below
        Debug.Print wsDest.Range("B2").Value
        Debug.Print wsDest.Range("B5").Value
    Next itm
    
    'Here we check if rowcounter does not equal 0. This indicates
    'that the loop ended with an odd number of elements, and should be
    'printed out to flush that "buffer"
    If rowCounter <> 0 Then
        'Do final printout
        Debug.Print wsDest.Range("B2").Value
        Debug.Print wsDest.Range("B5").Value
    End If


End Sub

Function GetUserInfo(rng As Range) As Collection
    Dim c As Collection
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim a(0 To 3)
    
    Set c = New Collection
    
    For Each cel In rng
        a(0) = cel.Value
        a(1) = cel.Offset(, 1).Value
        a(2) = cel.Offset(, 2).Value
        a(3) = cel.Offset(, 3).Value
        
        c.Add a
    Next cel
    
    'Return the collection
    Set GetUserInfo = c
End Function
```

I'd manage it a bit differently. First, I don't think it's wise to `ReDim` an array in a loop. I'm not sure how efficiently VBA manages resizing arrays, but it can be an expensive process.

I'd store the relevant values from each row into a collection. The items in the collection will be an array with the relevant fields. This collection can then be looped over, with the data being dropped into the relevant fields (and then printed, or whatever needs to be done).

Let me know if this gets you started.

```
Sub RunIt()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim coll As Collection
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    
    Set coll = GetUserInfo(rng)
    
    For Each itm In coll
        wsDest.Range("B2").Value = itm(0)
        wsDest.Range("D2").Value = itm(1)
        wsDest.Range("B3").Value = itm(2)
        wsDest.Range("D3").Value = itm(3)
        
        'Maybe do your print routine here, and then reload
    Next itm
End Sub

Function GetUserInfo(rng As Range) As Collection
    Dim c As Collection
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim a(0 To 3)
    
    Set c = New Collection
    
    For Each cel In rng
        a(0) = cel.Value
        a(1) = cel.Offset(, 1).Value
        a(2) = cel.Offset(, 2).Value
        a(3) = cel.Offset(, 3).Value
        
        c.Add a
    Next cel
    
    'Return the collection
    Set GetUserInfo = c
End Function
```

Comment: @MattWilliamson Try replacing `Set rngVisible = rng.Rows(xlCellTypeVisible)` with `Set rngVisible = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: Thanks, that was an easy one. the next issue has me perplexed though. My requirement is to write to 8 cells in the destination worksheet. I'm writing an instruction sheet and cutting it in half. So, 2 lines from the source are going to be written to 8 spots in the destination. I've tried expanding the array and adding more offsets but I'm not having any luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm going to edit my post with some code that should do the trick. Basically, it populates the collection in the same way: one entry per row. On the print/process side, we set a flag to indicate that it's time to print. So it will populate two rows of information, then process however you want. I tried to leave comments within the code to clarify the confusing parts. Comment back if it needs any changes.

Comment: This is great! I love how you left the code for future upgrades because I'm sure they will pop up while requirements change. I was attempting to do something similar but this is 1000 times better. The comments are spot on and It really helped me understand what you were doing. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: One last thing. If I want to move the second set of entries down the page to B30..D31, how would I do that? I've been playing around with it for a couple of hours and I can't figure it out.

Comment: @MattWilliamson In the edited code, the second set of entries is determined by `wsDest.Range("B2").Offset(rowCounter * 3).Value = itm(0)`. The code essentially says that the second entry coresponding to itm(0) should be offset 3 rows below the first. Since you'd want to change it to 28 rows below, try changing each of these entries to `wsDest.Range("B2").Offset(rowCounter * 28).Value = itm(0)'. Does that work?

Comment: Yes, that did it this time. I already tried that before and it didn't work. This workbook is acting really weird. sometimes when I run the sub, it just doesn't work. I have to save and close then re-open it and it works. I'm running `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Clear` between tests. Do you think that has anything to do with it?

Comment: @MattWilliamson `Cells.Clear` shouldn't affect anything since we are using hard-coded ranges on Sheet2. Is this the entirety of the macro that is running, or does this fit into other macros. If it consistently fails after an iteration, or with some other pattern, I'd debug it using F8 and see if there's anything wonky happening that maybe we missed.

Comment: I carved it out from my main code into a separate workbook. when I step through the code, it's really weird because when this happens, everything comes up Empty. It's at that point where I have to save it, exit out and open it back up. Then, on the first run, it works. but if I try to debug it, it fails again. Maybe the workbook is corrupted? I'm going to create a new one and see what happens.

Comment: @MattWilliamson I looked over the code, and there is one possibility. The following line: `Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)` doesn't actually qualify which sheet the range applies to. I should've fully qualified it. Try replacing it with: `Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)` . See if that fixes the problem. Without fully qualifying it, the code will just pick the active worksheet, which might not be sheet1.